# Default sound output after unplugging headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, headphones

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 connected to an external monitor via HDMI, whenever I plug the headphones (3.5mm jack) in, the output sound moves to them, which is fine, but when I unplug them, the output sound goes to the HDMI, but I want it to be the built-in speakers on the laptop. Is there any way to change the default output device after unplugging headphones?

My laptop is MSI GF63 Thin 11UC (16R6.1)

Thanks in advanced.